# How do I fill a Set with array of different object that extends the object in the Set

Tags: java, arrays, object, casting, set

How can I fill a `Set<SomeObject>`with array (`Object[]`) of different object that extends the object in the Set.

I got this array of objects which I want to cast into a Set of objects that extends the objects in the array Like this:

```
Object[] a = new Object[1];
a[0] = new SomeObject();
Set<SomeObject> aSet = new HashSet<SomeObject>(a);
```

If it is impossible to cast an array to a Set like that, is it then possible to cast an array to a List?

NOTE: If you want to achieve this the loop way like this:

```
Object[] a = new Object[1];
a[0] = new SomeObject("Something");
Set<SomeObject> aSet = new HashSet<SomeObject>();

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    aSet.add((SomeObject)a[i])  
}
```

But I don't want to do it the loop way, and, yes, I know all objects extends the java.lang.Object class.

Comment: Your code has absolutely nothing to do with casting. You should probably read something like this article to understand what object casting really means and how it works: http://www.volantec.biz/castingObjects.htm

Comment: @Natix I think the question is: I have an `Object[]`, which I know only contains `SomeObject` items. How can I fill a `Set<SomeObject>` without having to loop over each item and cast it from `Object` to `SomeObject`.

Comment: What's with the defacing of your own question? Pretty disrespectful towards those who have put the effort into answering it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to OP's recent comment:

> Somehow I can't cast this List to a Set so I let the method cast the List to a Array and return that Array

In that case you can simply do this:

```
List<SomeObject> list = ...
Set<SomeObject> set = new HashSet<SomeObject>(list);
```

What is important: This code has absolutely **nothing to do with casting**! What actually happens is that you have a `List` of objects and you create a new `Set` and copy all the elements from the list into it. The original list **isn't** modified by this operation.

To repeat my comment, you obviously have misunderstood what casting in Java means. Casting of object works in a very different way that casting of primitive values. Please read some article on this subject, such as this one:
http://www.volantec.biz/castingObjects.htm

Answer (score 2):

You decide first what you want to do with your UserObject.
  Wheather you to keep all your `UserObject` inside a array or you keep them under any collection.

Storing it twice is just meaning less to me,your just consuming more memory.

EDIT:

In this case use the below thing.

```
Set<T> mySet = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(someArray));
```

Comment: I am using hibernate to get a List of objects from the database these are returned by hibernate in a 'List' I got this method that gets a List a sertain Object with a maximum from the database. Somehow I can't cast this List to a Set so I let the method cast the List to a Array and return that Array. And I can cast this returned array of the method to a Set or List of any Object I want.
This is the header of my method:
public Object[] getObjects(int maxResults, Class CLASS) throws Exception

Comment: You Know that Set won't allow duplicate values and your List can have.So how it is good solution to try to put them in Set?

Comment: @JustmemyselfandI Of course you can't cast a List to a Set, they're not the same. What you can do is create your Set, then iterate through the List attempting to add each element to the Set, eliminating any duplicate objects in the List in the process.

Comment: @BOSS Because my database is created out of my domain objects and I got some ObjectProxy's defined using a Set<> because Hibernate accepts this and automatically creates a side table with composite primary key's. When I would use a List; hibernate wont declare any primay key's. So that is the reason I use a Set instead of a List

Comment: @AnthonyGrist So you suggest going trough the returned List<> using a for loop to fill a new Set<> so That i can return that Set<>? doesn't this cost more computer resources and slows the process down ?

Comment: @JustmemyselfandI More resources than going from List to array to Set? No, I doubt it.

Comment: @JustmemyselfandI Unless you have millions of items in your list, you won't notice the difference performance-wise. 1. Keep it simple. 2. If performance is not good enough, make it more complicated. Not the other way round.

Comment: @assylias but what is more efficient ? because eventually there will be hundreds of thousands of objects stored in the database... I convert the list to array like this: 
getResultList().toArray();

Comment: @JustmemyselfandI hundreds of thousands is not that many => keep it simple (what you called the noob way) until you notice a performance issue (which you probably won't).

Answer (score 2):

Declare `Object[] a = new Object[1];`  as `SomeObject[] a = new SomeObject[1];`

Use the below code:

```
SomeObject[] a = new SomeObject[1]
a[0] = new SomeObject();
Set<UserObject> aSet = new HashSet<UserObject>(Arrays.<UserObject> asList(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object[] a = new Object[3];
a[0] = new String("SAMIR1");
a[1] = new String("SAMIR2");
a[2] = new String("SAMIR3");
Set<Object> aSet = new HashSet<Object>(Arrays.<Object> asList(a));
System.out.println(aSet);
```

Comment: This won't compile - `a` is `Object[]`, not `UserObject[]`.

Comment: I see you removed the relevant part, but you could just do `Set<SomeObject> s = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(o));` (getting `Unsafe typecast`).